# UINavigationController popToViewController issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using UINavigationController to deal with controllers navigation

**In Normal Case**

RegistrationView ->
LoginView -> 
HomeView

From HomeView & any other next controllers there is one screen called Setting is opened up which is having Logout Button. On the click of this button screen will be popped to the LoginView in normal case.

```
- (IBAction)btnLogoutSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *navArr=self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *nav in navArr)
    {
        if ([nav isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:nav animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Once User will be registered & If user Logged in once, here application is having autoLogin functionality. So at that time LoginView will not be in the Navigation count. So in this scenario above code is not working. So at that time I am not able to go to the LoginView. I need help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you don't have an instance of `LoginViewController` on navigation stack, simply create it:

```
    LoginViewController* loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init]; //use appropriate initWith... method
```

Then you can use `viewControllers` property of UINavigationController. You can replace current view controller with `loginController`, or insert `loginController` at given index and pop to it.

```
NSMutableArray* newViewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[newViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:[newViewControllers indexOfObject:self] withObject:loginController];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer :) +1

To John: you can create your own `viewControllers` stack by copying `RegistrationViewController` and adding fresh created `LoginViewController` above it and then set the stack animated as proposed by Michal

Comment: @michal-ciuba Thanks, it is working properly & I got the concept behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:objLogin]) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:objLogin animated:TRUE];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:objLogin animated:TRUE];
        }
```

Comment: you are right, this can work well, But the at the time of auto login scenario, LoginView will not be added to the navigation so it is not in the navigationController count.

Comment: you are perfectly Right, at that time I was not much aware about navigation.